# Storing Date in Hibernate with millisecond precision

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to persist a Date object in Hibernate with millisecond precision.

```
private Date date = new Date();

@Column(columnDefinition="DATETIME(3)")
public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}
```

But in the database the millisecond component is always .000. Is it simply not possible to store a Date object with millisecond precision using Hibernate?

Comment: `java.util.Date` already contains millisecond precision. This should work alright for you at both db and ORM level. What version of Mysql and hibernate are you on?

Answer (score 1):

java.util.date will only persist down to the second, since this is mapped to an SQL DATE type by the ORM, which may not contain milliseconds (at least in implementations I'm familiar with).

[java.sql.timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) supports fractional seconds.

I would definitely look into using the new Java 8 date libraries if you're able (or joda if you can't use Java 8).  They're much better.

Comment: I've already tried changing the field to Timestamp, it has no effect.

Comment: Terrible advice about switching to Java 8 date libraries as Hibernate support for them is very bad at the moment.

Comment: Yep, the following type supports Java 8: `@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")`

Answer (score -1):

This is consistent with the documented behavior of [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and [java.sql.Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)

java.util.Date stores down to the second, and java.sql.Timestamp is a thin wrapper to accommodate the nanosecond value of a SQL timestamp value. If you read the note on the Timestamp javadoc, it clearly states this difference.

If you don't want to lose your second fractions, and don't want to investigate alternative date libraries (e.g.[Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/quickstart.html)) you'll need to make the field a java.sql.Timestamp, and use the milisecond value of the current date to construct the initial value

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

Comment: The documentation clearly states "The class Date represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision.". The compareTo method of Date also compares Date objects to millisecond precision. Changing the field (as well as the database column) to timestamp has no effect.

Answer (score -1):

Try updating database connector version (.jar or dependency in case you use build automation tool). It worked for me. I used simple `java.util.Date` and DATETIME(3) in MySQL.